# Difference between HttpContext.User.Identity and IClaimsPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, claims-based-identity, adfs2.0

I am new to identity systems development and I'm thinking of using claims principal and claims identity for authorization in ASP.NET MVC 3 architecture (implemented at controller level).

I can see few implementation which uses `HttpContext.User.Identity` for authorization and some using `IClaimsPrincipal`. From my understanding (poor) through several posts, `IClaimsPrincipal` is a claim-based approach to provide `HttpContext.User.Identity` context to the application level usage. What is the difference between those two approaches and which one is more effecient if I use ADFS 2.0 as an STS/FP service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IClaimsPrincipal` is the WIF extension of `IPrincipal`. `IClaimsPrincipal` offers a collection of `IClaimsIdentity`, and likewise, `IClaimsIdentity` inherits `IIdentity`.

If you're using WIF in ASP.NET, `IClaimsPrincipal`/`IClaimsIdentity` and `HttpContext.User.Identity` are effectively the same approach. As part of the authentication pipeline, WIF will set your `HttpContext.User.Identity` to an `IClaimsIdentity` so that you can access it like so:

```
IClaimsIdentity claimsId = HttpContext.User.Identity as IClaimsIdentity;
```